# Applying function to dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, function, one-hot-encoding

I have the following function (one-hot encoding function that takes a column as an input). I basically want to apply it to a column in my dataframe, but can't seem to understand what's going wrong.

```
def dummies(dataframe, col):
    dataframe[col] = pd.Categorical(dataframe[col])
    pd.concat([dataframe,pd.get_dummies(dataframe[col],prefix = 'c')],axis=1)

df1 = df['X'].apply(dummies)
```

Guessing something is wrong with how I'm calling it?

Comment: Did you try just calling it like this: `df1 = dummies(df, 'X')`

Comment: you need to return a value .. that should fix it, although I can't test it without example df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make sure you're returning a value from the function, currently you are not..also when you apply a function to a column you are basically passing the value of each row in the column into the function, so your function is set up wrong..typically you'd do it like this:

```
def function1(value):
    new_value = value*2 #some operation
    return new_value
```

then:

```
df['X'].apply(function1)
```

currently your function is set up to take entire df, and the name of a column, so likely your function might work if you call it like this:

```
df1 = dummies(df, 'X')
```

but you still need to add a return statement

Comment: Thanks Derek, can't believe I missed the return statement. Side question.. is it possible to apply this function to multiple columns in one line?

Comment: like apply the same function to multiple columns individually? or apply a function that uses multiple columns as input?

Comment: in either case, check these questions, they cover both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519983/how-to-apply-a-function-to-multiple-columns-in-pandas and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply it to that one column you don't need to make a new dataframe. This is the correct syntax. [Please read the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```py
df['X'] = df['X'].apply(lambda x : dummies(x))
```

Comment: what if they want to make a new df with the results