# Applying a function to list of columns of a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I scraped this table from this URL:

"https://www.patriotsoftware.com/blog/accounting/average-cost-living-by-state/"

Which looks like this:

```
 State  Annual Mean Wage (All Occupations)  Median Monthly Rent Value of a Dollar
    0   Alabama $44,930 $998    $1.15
    1   Alaska  $59,290 $1,748  $0.95
    2   Arizona $50,930 $1,356  $1.04
    3   Arkansas    $42,690 $953    $1.15
    4   California  $61,290 $2,518  $0.87
```

And then I wrote this function to help me turn the strings into ints:

```
def money_string_to_int(s):
return int(s.replace(",", "").replace("$",""))

money_string_to_int("$1,23")
```

My function works when I apply it to only one column. I found this answer here about using on multiple columns: [How to apply a function to multiple columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519983/how-to-apply-a-function-to-multiple-columns-in-pandas)

But my code below does not work and produces no errors:

```
ls = ['Annual Mean Wage (All Occupations)', 'Median Monthly Rent',
       'Value of a Dollar']

ppe_table[ls] = ppe_table[ls].apply(money_string_to_int)
```

Comment: You just need to use `.str` in `s` before using `replace`.

Comment: I did that before it gives me this error:

'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try

```
df.set_index('State').apply(lambda x: (x.str.replace('[$,]','').astype(float))).reset_index()
```

Comment: Ok thank you this works. I have another geodataframe that has some more wage data but it also has some co-ordinates in a column. How would I select a subset of those columns? Is it just df['a','b'].rest_of_your_code?

Comment: Are you able to add the coordinates columns to your sample df?

Comment: Yeah, I can merge this cost of living data frame with the coordinates columns on a "State" column. I ended up just creating a temporary data frame without the coordinate stuff, using your function, and then re-merging that geo dataframe and then merging that with this cost of living dataframe. A little messy but whatever. Thank you so much!